# The TIFF Group 5 compression

Tags: format, tiff

Are TIFF Group 5 compression and LZW compression the same thing?

Comment: Some words are synonyms.  Some are anyonyms.

Comment: @Gurdas: you mean antonyms. (Some are homonyms, some are eponyms...)

Answer (score 3):

I've been working with TIFF files for a long time and I've never heard LZW compression referred to as TIFF GROUP 5. I've always called them simply LZW Compressed Tiffs.

**The only "group" designation for compression are:**
CCITT Group 3
CCITT Group 4

I think you may be confusing the TIFF format versions which now go up to 6.

More Info from the owner of the format (Adobe): [Tiff Resources](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/tiff/index.html)